# Face up or Face down LandScape Orientation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10, ios12

I am curios about faceUp, faceDown landScape orientation in swift 4.2 perviously there were helpers methods to check faceUp, faceDown in landscape orientation. Any one know about the alternative of this helper function. Thanks in Advance.

```
UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i Fixed my problem using status bar orientation.

```
if UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .landscapeLeft || UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .landscapeRight || UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape { return true}
```

So if you are using `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape` this function you can replace it with above code.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some searches and the replacement for:

```
UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)
```

is

```
UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
```